# Remove files in given folder but leave files in subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I think this should be rather simple but I want to delete all the files that are stated in for example: `C:\TEST` but I want to leave the files that are located in subdirectories of this  folder. For example files in the folder: `C:\TEST\Backup` should not be deleted.

When using the following batch command all the files get deleted including those located in sub directories but it leaves the folder:

```
DEL /S C:\TEST\ /q
```

Does anyone know the command that I need?

Comment: Skip the /S perhaps ?!?

Comment: As @Marged wrote. Why are you using the `/S - Delete specified files from all subdirectories` switch if it's exactly what's you don't want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

from cmdline:

```
for %a IN (C:\TEST\*.*) do echo "%a"
```

**OR** In a batch script, just add an additional `%`

```
for %%a IN (C:\TEST\*.*) do echo "%%a"
```

Just replace `echo` with `del` once you are confident with your final script.

**OR** simply doing:

```
del C:\TEST /q
```

All these things can be found by simply opening cmd.exe and running ANY of the commands with the `/?` switch. For instance.

```
for /?
del /?
```

etc.